# How to specify a timeout to Azure KeyVaultManagementClient async call?

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-keyvault, azure-management-api

I'm accessing Azure KeyVault from .NET. If my internet connectivity is blocked, Vaults.GetAsync will take about 2 minutes to time out. I'd rather set this to something like 10 seconds.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
AzureCredentials creds = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
KeyVaultManagementClient kvMgmtClient = new KeyVaultManagementClient(creds);
kvMgmtClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

vault = kvMgmtClient.Vaults.GetAsync(resourceGroupName, vaultName).Result;
```

I tried setting `ManagementClient.LongRunningOperationRetryTimeout`, but this had no effect.

I also tried using a CancellationToken, like so:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(10000);

AzureCredentials creds = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
KeyVaultManagementClient kvMgmtClient = new KeyVaultManagementClient(creds);
kvMgmtClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
vault = kvMgmtClient.Vaults.GetAsync(resourceGroupName, vaultName, cts.Token).Result;
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect either. What am I doing wrong?